# fatal error "invalid image file type" import file - magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I am running script for importing products. For some of the skus it is giving ->

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid image file type.' in
>   /home/oceanf7p/public_html/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace:
>
> /home/oceanf7p/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php(282):
>
> Mage::throwException('Invalid image f...')
>
> /home/oceanf7p/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(1042):
>
> Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media->addImage(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '/home/oceanf7p/...', Array, false, false)
>
> /home/oceanf7p/public_html/import-products.php(341):
>
> Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->addImageToMediaGallery('/home/oceanf7p/...',
>
> Array, false, false) #3 {main} thrown in
>
> /home/oceanf7p/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 595

I checked for image file extension also. its jpg only.

this is happening with some skus while others are imported successfully.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @ Raul : Check the image files with errors Files saved with .jpg extension are not always valid .jpg files How to check it?? I almost tried everything but now clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Check the image files with errors

Files saved with .jpg extension are not always valid .jpg files

Answer (score 0):

```
$productSKU = $data[0];
$ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
$mySaveDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS ;

                    //$filename = basename($urlToImage);
$filename = $data[61];
$completeSaveLoc = $mySaveDir.$filename;
if(file_exists($completeSaveLoc))
{ 
    $ourProduct->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()));//media gallery initialization
    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($completeSaveLoc, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),false, false);
    $ourProduct->save();
    echo "done ";
}

if($data[62] != '')
{
    $extraimg = $data[62];
    $ourProduct1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    $imagesaveloc = $mySaveDir.$extraimg;
    if(file_exists($imagesaveloc))
    {
        echo "file there";
        $ourProduct1->addImageToMediaGallery($imagesaveloc, null,false,false);
        $ourProduct1->save();

    }
}

if($data[63] != '')
{
    $extraimg2 = $data[63];
    $ourProduct2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    $imagesaveloc = $mySaveDir.$extraimg2;
    if(file_exists($imagesaveloc))
    {
        echo "file there";
        $ourProduct2->addImageToMediaGallery($imagesaveloc, null,false,false);
        $ourProduct2->save();

    }
}

if($data[64] != '')
{
    $extraimg3 = $data[64];
    $ourProduct3 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    $imagesaveloc = $mySaveDir.$extraimg3;
    if(file_exists($imagesaveloc))
    {
        echo "file there";
        $ourProduct3->addImageToMediaGallery($imagesaveloc, null,false,false);
        $ourProduct3->save();

    }
}

if($data[65] != '')
{
    $extraimg4 = $data[65];
    $ourProduct4 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    $imagesaveloc = $mySaveDir.$extraimg4;
    if(file_exists($imagesaveloc))
    {
        echo "file there";
        $ourProduct4->addImageToMediaGallery($imagesaveloc, null,false,false);
        $ourProduct4->save();

    }
}

if($data[66] != '')
{
    $extraimg4 = $data[66];
    $ourProduct4 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    $imagesaveloc = $mySaveDir.$extraimg4;
    if(file_exists($imagesaveloc))
    {
        echo "file there";
        $ourProduct4->addImageToMediaGallery($imagesaveloc, null,false,false);
        $ourProduct4->save();

    }
}
```

I have done coding for 10 images.